# How to re use the code from a class based view - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django/Django rest framework class-based view. If it is a repeated question kindly excuse.

Consider I have a class-based views like this.

```
class UserBucket(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        ...
        ...
        return Response(some_data)
    def put(self, request):
        ...
        ...
        return Response(some_data)

class FilterView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        data_to_filter = request.query_params.get('filterData')
        # filter logic goes here
        ...
        ...
        return Response(filtred_data)
```

If I want to use this FilterView code in the UserBucket's put method so that I can maintain DRY principle how can I achieve it? 
What I really want to do here is that from UserBucket put method I want to call the FilterView's get method with few arguments and get back the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Generic views with Mixins or you can dive in their code to learn how to implement like that

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py

Comment: Isn't it possible to do the same with APIView inherited class based view?

Comment: Because the filter and userbucket functionality is complicated.

Comment: if you want to reuse your business logic, you can define it in manager object of your model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/